Is a sealed/unvented or vented crawlspace better?
I have read articles that a sealed crawlspace is usually drier than an insulated vented crawlspace. I have a vented crawlspace that is vented but is dry. Problem is some of the insulation is falling. Other problem is when I bought the house my home inspector advised that because the insulation is not up against the subfloor my HVAC is not running efficiently, which I would agree with as it stays on almost constantly to keep my house cool. I was going to push up the existing insulation and add an R13 for good measure but when I checked out the joists, they are 16" tall engineered open joists so just zig-zagged 2x4's between a top and bottom 2x4 leaving little to no where to use the metal stays/insulation supports to hold it up. I am rethinking what is the best solution. I was thinking about putting plastic up on the joist and trying blown insulation but not sure how well that would work. Ultimately I just want to make sure my crawlspace is properly insulated and my HVAC works efficiently. I am considering just sealing my vents and making it a closed crawlspace. Any advice/suggestions? Thanks. Don

How tall is your crawlspace and how big is the home?

@Matthew. It is about 3' tall. House is 1465 SF
